# How to use a list of variable in the operation in a loop (or lapply)?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I would like to run a series of analysis using different variables from a list. These variables are in the same dataset.

sample data frame is as below

```
df <- data.frame(x1=runif(10),
             x2=runif(10),
             x3=runif(10),
             x4=runif(10),
             y=runif(10))

# I would like to use variables from this list
xlist <- c("x1","x2","x3")

summary<-NA
```

my thought is to use for loop or lapply, but it seems that both methods have the same problem when calling the variable from the list.
The problem is that I use "var" in the loop to represent x1,x2,or x3, but functions like "lm" require an argument of "data", and the function will recognize var as the variable to call, instead of x1,x2,or x3.

Any idea how can I avoid this?

```
# using for loop
for (var in xlist) {
  model <- lm(y~var,data=df)
  temp <- data.frame(coef=model$coefficients[2])
  summary<- rbind(summary,temp)
}

# using lapply
func <- function(var){
  model <- lm(y~var,data=df)
  temp <- data.frame(coef=model$coefficients[2])
}

result <- lapply(xlist, func)
```

Comment: I would just change the one line to `model <- lm(y~.,data=df[, c('y', var)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need the `formula` function...

```
for (var in xlist) {
  form <- formula(paste0("y~",var))
  model <- lm(form,data=df)
  temp <- data.frame(coef=model$coefficients[2])
  summary<- rbind(summary,temp)
}

summary
         coef
x1  0.3626764
x2 -0.3194918
x3  0.1216511
```

It should work in exactly the same way with `lapply` (or you might prefer `sapply`).

Comment: Thank you. In this case, both `form = reformulate(var, "y")`, and `form <- formula(paste0("y~",var))` work. I find that `df[[a]]` is also helpful.